# After application uses the same package name in AppGallery and GooglePlaystore, it is removed due to Google Play protection

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

Application is removed playstore by  Google Protect.

1. Every release the version code from Huawei App Gallery is always higher than the version code in Play Store.
2. The new release version code in the Play Store will higher than the previous release version code in both Play Store and App Gallery.
3. But the rolling out percentage between the two stores is different. Not sure it would affect

Please help with another quick question. What will happen to App Gallery auto-update if we release the app in Huawei App Store with a different Keystore than the release in Google Play Store?

Answer (score 4):

For the overwriting of each other from AppGallery and Google Play store problem, the root cause is the apps are using the same package name and the same signing key in conjunction with auto-update from both stores. When there is a higher version available from either store, the Android system would recognize it, download and update the app, which would cause overwrite.

The answer is actually in the second question. Using a new keystore for AppGallery would make the app different from the app from GPS from Android system point of view. Please use a new keystore for AG release, there will not be any overwritten problem once this update. Remember to update the SHA256 signature in AG for the new release.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this? It would be more convenient for me to have the same package name but the problem is that once I release the app this can't be changed and then if the problem appears there's no way of fixing it.

Comment: @IvanIčin I am positive about this. You can always use the new Key in the kay store. Please see the 2nd paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Have you tried and did it work?

Answer (score -1):

This is a message displayed on Google Protect. We could not restrict the play protect. You can disable Google Protect on your phone manually.
In addition, Google Protect is a black-box detection, which is claimed to be an intelligent detection and may display a message for all apps that are not downloaded by Google Play.

Based on the warning message, this message comes in "Backdoor" category(refer below link).
https://developers.google.com/android/play-protect/warning-strings

Also you can refer the below link
https://developers.google.com/android/play-protect/client-protections#developer-appeal

So you can contact google support team regarding this.